# Trying to make an expression eval function in java natively

Tags: java

I am making a challenge for my self where I create the function 'eval()' (from python) on Java without any importing any additional libraries. But I'm stuck when I face "-20-10".

My code basically splits a string into two (a and b) when an operator is found.

```
String equ = "-20-10" // The first "-" is found
String a = "";
String b = "20-10";
```

String a and b then gets into a recursive loop. But in this case, **a** will be "(empty)" and outputs an error.

```
String equ = "20-10";
String a = "20";
String b = "10";
```

The error has something to do with the logic of the program and I can't seem to figure it out, guidance needed.

```
private String calc(String equ) {
        String result = equ;
        if(equ.contains("+")) {
            System.out.println("+ found");
            String a = equ.substring(0, equ.indexOf('+'));
            System.out.println("+ a:"+a);
            String b = equ.substring(equ.indexOf('+')+1);
            System.out.println("+ b:"+b);
            a = calc(a);
            System.out.println(a+" + "+b);
            b = calc(b);
            result = String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(a)+Double.valueOf(b));
            System.out.println("+ result:"+result);
        }
        else if (equ.contains("-")) {
                System.out.println("- found:");
                String a = equ.substring(0, equ.indexOf('-'));
                System.out.println("- a:"+a);
                String b = equ.substring(equ.indexOf('-')+1);
                System.out.println("- b:"+b);
                a = calc(a);
                System.out.println(a+" - "+b);
                b = calc(b);
                result = String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(a)-Double.valueOf(b));
                System.out.println("- result:"+result);
        }
        else if (equ.contains("/")) {
            System.out.println("/ found:");
            String a = equ.substring(0, equ.indexOf('/'));
            System.out.println("/ a:"+a);
            String b = equ.substring(equ.indexOf('/')+1);
            System.out.println("/ b:"+b);
            a = calc(a);
            System.out.println(a+" / "+b);
            b = calc(b);
            result = String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(a)/Double.valueOf(b));
            System.out.println("/ result:"+result);
        }
        else if(equ.contains("*")) {
            System.out.println("* found:");
            String a = equ.substring(0, equ.indexOf('*'));
            System.out.println("* a:"+a);
            String b = equ.substring(equ.indexOf('*')+1);
            System.out.println("* b:"+b);
            a = calc(a);
            System.out.println(a+" * "+b);
            b = calc(b);
            result = String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(a)*Double.valueOf(b));
            System.out.println("* result:"+result);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you will need a real parser, rather the what you have there. You have an equation that has both a binary minus and a binary minus.

Comment: @NomadMaker that's a good idea, thanks!

Comment: I meant both a unary minus and a binary minus. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Tour problem is when you call to `calc()` with `"-20"`, he seperate the String to `""` and `"20"`, so when tou call `Double.valueOf("")` he throws a `NumberFormatException`.
To fix that issue, just change the plus and minus if statments to:

```
if(equ.substring(1).contains("+")) {
            System.out.println("+ found");
            String a = equ.substring(0, equ.lastIndexOf('+'));
            System.out.println("+ a:"+a);
            String b = equ.substring(equ.lastIndexOf('+')+1);
            System.out.println("+ b:"+b);
            a = calc(a);
            System.out.println(a+" + "+b);
            b = calc(b);
            result = String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(a)+Double.valueOf(b));
            System.out.println("+ result:"+result);
        }
        else if (equ.substring(1).contains("-")) {
                System.out.println("- found:");
                String a = equ.substring(0, equ.lastIndexOf('-'));
                System.out.println("- a:"+a);
                String b = equ.substring(equ.lastIndexOf('-')+1);
                System.out.println("- b:"+b);
                a = calc(a);
                System.out.println(a+" - "+b);
                b = calc(b);
                result = String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(a)-Double.valueOf(b));
                System.out.println("- result:"+result);
        }
```

That make the function see `"-20"` as `"-20"` and not as `""` minus `"20"`.